# How to draw a crescent (similar to slur or tie) using Tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to draw a crescent symbol (used for Indic music notation) using tikz. I have almost done with the drawing but got a problem with the output. The outcome is given below

[image]

The code is given below

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[squarednode/.style={rectangle, minimum size=5mm}, node distance=2mm]
    \node[squarednode] (1) {1};
    \node[squarednode] [right=of 1] (2) {2};
    \node[squarednode] [right=of 2] (3) {3};

    \draw [fill=black, draw=black] (1.south) to [out=315,in=225] (3.south);
    \draw [fill=white, draw=white] (1.south) to [out=325,in=215] (3.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Everything is working fine but there is a horizontal thin black line from the start to the end of the image which is not required.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The line is an artefact of the method you are using to blank out part of your picture and is due to the fact that pdf viewers add a little blurring to the edges of filled regions. It shouldn't appear when printed. To remove it when viewed, fill just the part between the paths rather than filling too much and erasing.  Alternatively, the calligraphy library can create tapered paths which might suit you.

Comment: As @AndrewStacey says: `\fill[black] (1.south) to [out=315,in=225] (3.south) to [out=215,in=325] (1.south);`

Comment: @Chandan In music we call this a slur (or a tie), but not a crescent.

Comment: I know @C.Peters. Actually the symbol is meend (Indian music symbol in Akarmatrik notation system) which resembles slur or tie. That's why I did not mention it with the staff notation name.

Comment: For future reference, please post a full document so answers don't have to guess parts of your code (such as the locations of the nodes).  See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that for some background on why we ask this.

Comment: @AndrewStacey I have edited the question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to draw a single closed path instead of overlaying one path with another. This way, the artefact will not show up. You can do like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\coordinate (1) at (0,0);
\coordinate (3) at (2,0);

%\draw [fill=black, draw=black] (1.south) to [out=315,in=225] (3.south); 
%\draw [fill=white, draw=white] (1.south) to [out=325,in=215] (3.south);

\draw [fill=black, draw=black] (1.south) to [out=315,in=225] (3.south)
    to [out=215,in=325] cycle;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, NBur was quicker in posting the very same answer as a comment. So credit should go to them.

Comment: As a side note, it would be interesting to evaluate the out and in angles depending of the length of the crescent (like for the curly braces, for instance). But it requires more work.

Comment: You were quicker, since you posted a full answer!

Comment: By the way, you don't need to write `fill=black, draw=black`. Black is used by default so you can remove those, makes for cleaner code. If you need to override another color then using `\filldraw[black]` should work.

Answer (score 9):

Just to demonstrate a different option, here's how to achieve this with the `calligraphy` library.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calligraphy}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\calligraphy[copperplate,weight=light] (0,0) to[out=320,in=220] +(2,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: calligraphic crescent]

Comment: Very beautiful this option using \usetikzlibrary{calligraphy}.